# Need to find transactions which are split and by themsleves

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of SKU's which are only POD in a separate table. I need to find the transactions which have the POD SKU in it and the transactions which have POD SKU and also some other SKU with it.

I have attached a sample database which I created.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c2150662b298b8d172c6902514ada52a

and this is the data in those tables:

```
select * from transaction_detail_mv;

INDIVIDUAL_ID DOLLAR_VALUE_US   QUANTITY TRANSACTION_NUMBER SKU        TXN_DATE   BRAND   IS_MERCH CURRE L
------------- --------------- ---------- ------------------ ---------- ---------- ----- ---------- ----- -
            1              10         30                567 903633     2019-02-01 BRAND          1 USD   S
            1              20         30                567 123767     2019-02-01 BRAND          1 USD   S
            1              10         40                345 773633     2019-02-10 BRAND          1 USD   S
            1              12         30                345 965322     2019-02-10 BRAND          1 USD   S
            1              10         50                678 838364     2019-02-15 BRAND          1 USD   S
            1              10         70                975 983636     2019-02-28 BRAND          1 USD   S
            2              11         80                910 363635     2019-02-11 BRAND          1 USD   S
            2              11         90                323 566373     2019-02-12 BRAND          1 USD   S
            3              11         62                855 678364     2019-02-12 BRAND          1 USD   S
```

```
select * from POD_SKU;

SKU       
----------
903633
773633
838364
678364
```

For example, transaction numbers 567 and 345 would be split transactions because they each have a POD SKU as well as some other SKU in the same transaction. And transactions 975 and 855 would be single transactions because they only have POD SKUs.

This is the format I am looking for:
        [txn_count    sum(quantity)
split       2             ?
single      2             ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZVfn.png)

Comment: How far have you got already (is there a query that partially works you can add to the question)? And what output are you looking for?

Comment: Also do you really means that 975 is split, as it doesn't have a POD SKU at all? Maybe you actually meant 678 and 855?

Comment: @AlexPoole yes thats correct. also I am not able to figure out a way to show them in a count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an outer join between your tables to include both POD and non-POD SKUs, and then use case expressions and possibly analytic (windowed) functions to compare across rows for the same transaction; for example:

```
select td.transaction_number, td.sku,
  case when ps.sku is not null
       then 'Yes'
       else 'No'
  end as is_pod_sku,
  case when count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number) > 0
       then 'Yes'
       else 'No'
  end as has_pod_sku,
  case when count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number) > 0
       and  count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number)
              < count(*) over (partition by td.transaction_number)
       then 'Yes'
       else 'No'
  end as is_split
from transaction_detail_mv td
left join pod_sku ps on ps.sku = td.sku;

TRANSACTION_NUMBER SKU        IS_POD_SKU HAS_POD_SKU IS_SPLIT
------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------- --------
               323 566373     No         No          No      
               345 773633     Yes        Yes         Yes     
               345 965322     No         Yes         Yes     
               567 123767     No         Yes         Yes     
               567 903633     Yes        Yes         Yes     
               678 838364     Yes        Yes         No      
               855 678364     Yes        Yes         No      
               910 363635     No         No          No      
               975 983636     No         No          No
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b3e46bded17a746c313e5e28407db1b7)

You can then then filter out those with `has_pod_sku` of 'No'. Obviously (hopefully) you can include whatever columns you want from the original table, I've just shown the two that seemed most relevant at this point. And you can use 0/1 or Y/N flags or more descriptive text instead if 'Yes' and 'No'. The details depend on exactly what you want to see in the end.

---

> is there a way to count them

You could use the query above as a subquery and count each flag value (after excluding those with no POD SKUs at all):

```
select count(distinct case when is_split = 'Yes' then transaction_number end) as split,
  count(distinct case when is_split = 'No' then transaction_number end) as single
from (
  select td.transaction_number, td.sku,
    case when count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number) > 0
         then 'Yes'
         else 'No'
    end as has_pod_sku,
    case when count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number) > 0
         and  count(ps.sku) over (partition by td.transaction_number)
                < count(*) over (partition by td.transaction_number)
         then 'Yes'
         else 'No'
    end as is_split
  from transaction_detail_mv td
  left join pod_sku ps on ps.sku = td.sku
)
where has_pod_sku = 'Yes';

     SPLIT     SINGLE
---------- ----------
         2          2
```

or more simply:

```
select count(case when sku_count > pod_sku_count then transaction_number end) as split,
  count(case when sku_count = pod_sku_count then transaction_number end) as single
from (
  select td.transaction_number,
    count(*) as sku_count,
    count(ps.sku) as pod_sku_count
  from transaction_detail_mv td
  left join pod_sku ps on ps.sku = td.sku
  group by td.transaction_number
)
where pod_sku_count > 0;

     SPLIT     SINGLE
---------- ----------
         2          2
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=332464787043518d1fab6c4156989992) with those two queries added.

Comment: is there a way to count them and give the result in the following format: split transaction - (count)
single transactions -( count)

Comment: Well, you can just use the query I showed as a subquery (inline view or CTE) and count how many have `is_split` as yes and how many have `is_split` as no? But is that all you want to know - not which transactions are involved or anythign else about them?

Comment: This works but I was trying to add the quantity for each transactions but it does not give me anything

Comment: It would still really help if you included the output you're actually looking for in your question. I don't how your last two comments work together; the first says you want total counts of transactions, the second says you want to count - something? for each transaction. But each transaction is either split or not, so I don't see how you do both.

Comment: I just need the count of the split and the single transactions and I also want the sum of their quantities

Comment: txn_count     quantity
split                2
Single             2

this is the format I was looking for I am able to get the total quantity but not the quantity for single and split seperately

Comment: Can you help me find the summed quantities